# $p$ and $q$ not having $2$ as a common factor, thus $q$ must be an odd natural number?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

So, I was looking at this proof of the irrationality of square root $2$ and came across this alternate proof. I am familiar with the common proof of the irrationality of square root 2 presented in most books.  $(p/q)^2 = 2$
Since $p^2 = 2q^2$, we see that $p^2$ is even. This implies that $p$ is also even.
Which is fine but then I got stumped by this - since $p$ and $q$ do not have 2 as a common factor, then $q$ must be an odd natural number. Can someone please explain this specific line? I thought we were looking at the square of $p$ equalling $2$ into the square of $q$. How does he/she find out q is an odd natural number.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have proved that p is even, p will have 2 as a factor. But since p and q don't share 2 as a common factor, q wont have 2 as a factor. If a number isn't divisible by 2, it is odd. Hence q is odd

Comment: goodness! Thank you! So this part has nothing to do with (/)^2=2 ,right? It is just related to the initial assuption of p/q being not reducible

Comment: Yes, the proof relies on the initial assumption that p and q are coprime.